# Reading the properties of Discrete Fourier Transformation from the given figure.

Tags: fourier-analysis

Can anybody please help me read the properties of Discrete Fourier Transformation from the given figure. [Here is the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZi4J.png)

Thank you guys, appreciate you help.

Comment: What you are seeing are the amplitudes for the various complex sines that - when combined linearly - approximate the original function. Because the sines are complex, there are two graphs; one for the imaginary and one for the real part.

Comment: So, which property of DFT does the image shows?

Comment: The amplitudes.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the real part $X_R[k]$ satisfies

$$X_R[k]=X_R[N-k]\tag{1}$$

where $N$ is the DFT length. The imaginary part satisfies

$$X_I[k]=-X_I[N-k]\tag{2}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives the following condition for the complex DFT $X[k]=X_R[k]+iX_I[k]$:

$$X[k]=X^*[N-k]\tag{3}$$

where $*$ denotes complex conjugation.
Equation $(3)$ means that the original sequence $x[n]$ (the DFT of which is $X[k]$) is *real-valued*.